# TableModelListener don't work

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listener

I have a problem with the TableModelListener. I have to make sure that when the user changes the value in the cell, this value is stored in the database.

The problem is that even though I added the listener when I edit the contents of a cell, it does nothing.

where am I wrong?

File whit table

```
public class Pianificatore extends javax.swing.JFrame  {



private FrontController iFc = new FC();

    private ADISysTableModel modelPazientiTable;

public Pianificatore() {      
        initComponents();
        aggiornaTabelle();


        tabellaPazienti.getModel().addTableModelListener(new  AdisysTableModelListener(tabellaPazienti)); 

}
```

And this is my TableModelListener

```
package adisys.server.strumenti;

import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;


public class AdisysTableModelListener implements TableModelListener {
    JTable table;

    public AdisysTableModelListener(JTable table) {
       this.table = table;
    }

    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
       System.out.println("ciao");
    }
}
```

This is the table model

```
public class ADISysTableModel extends AbstractTableModel implements TableModel {
    ResultSet dati;

public ADISysTableModel(ResultSet nuoviDati) {
        dati = nuoviDati;

        try {
            //Trace
            System.out.println("- Creazione modello tabella: \""+ dati.getMetaData().getTableName(1) +"\"");
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {

        try {
            return dati.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("ERRORE: Calcolo del numero di colonne errato.");
            return 0;
        }
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {

        try {
            //Seleziona l'ultimo elemento
            dati.last();
            //Restituisce l'indice dell'elemento
            return (dati.getRow());


        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("ERRORE: Calcolo del numero di righe errato. (metodo getRowCount() )");
            return 0;
        }
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int riga, int colonna) {

        try {
            //Sposta il cursore alla riga desiderata (con sfasamento di 1)
            dati.absolute(riga+1);

            //Estrae il valore nella colonna specificata e lo restituisce (con sfasamento di 1)
            return dati.getObject(colonna+1);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // In caso di errore restituisce un oggetto vuoto
            e.printStackTrace();

            //Trace
            System.out.println("ERRORE: Valore dell'elemento della tabella non valido.");
            return null;
        }
}

@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int rIndex, int cIndex) {
        return true;
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int col) {
    try {
        return dati.getMetaData().getColumnName(col+1);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // Eccezione
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "?";
    }
}

public Integer getID(int riga)
{
    //Ricerca colonna ID
    for(int i=0; i<=getColumnCount(); i++)
        if(getColumnName(i).equals("ID"))
            return i;
    return null;
}


/**
 * Restituisce l'indice della colonna a partire dal nome della colonna ricercata
 * <b>N.B. L'indice della prima colonna è 0, l'ultimo è numeroColonne-1.</b>
 * @param Nome - Stringa con il nome della colonna
 * @return -1 se la colonna non e' stata trovata, altrimenti l'indice della colonna
 */
public int getColumnIndex(String Nome)  {
    for (int i=0; i<getColumnCount();i++)
        if( getColumnName(i)==Nome) return i;
    return -1;
}


}
```

Comment: Please post only the relevant parts...

Comment: Better to post an [sscce](http://sscce.org). This way we can work with compilable runnable code that shows your problem but without all the other code that is completely unrelated to your problem and only serves as a distraction to us.

Comment: Just guessting from what I can see: normally, the table model is responsible for managing listeners (register/unregister) and also triggers the listeners on events. Maybe your table model `ADISysTableModel` (which I can't see from the code you provided) does not implement/support listeners?